# Solve: $ye^{xy}\mathrm dx+(xe^{xy}+2y)\mathrm dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Exact Differential Equations and Integrating Factor:**

Solve: $ye^{xy}\mathrm dx+(xe^{xy}+2y)\mathrm dy=0$

**My Trial:**

*Seeing the $xy$ term, I think of solving it using the following rule:*

If $M\mathrm dx+N\mathrm dy=0$ is of the form $f_1(xy)y\mathrm dx+f_2(xy)x\mathrm dy=0$ and $Mx-Ny \ne 0 $ then integrating factor

$=\dfrac{1}{Mx-Ny}$

**However,**

When I am trying to take $x$ as common from $N$, I get a term $\dfrac{y}{x}$ and cannot solve the equation.

Which other way can I solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write
$$ye^{xy}\mathrm dx+(xe^{xy}+2y)\mathrm dy=0$$
$$e^{xy}(y\mathrm dx+x\mathrm dy)=-2y\mathrm dy$$
$$e^{xy}\mathrm d(xy)=-\mathrm d(y^2)$$
$$\mathrm d\left(e^{xy}\right)=-\mathrm d(y^2)$$
$$e^{xy}=-y^2+C$$

Comment: Better also introduce Lambert W function to solve for $y$.

Comment: Sir, can you answer this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2875818/394202

Answer (score 1):

Given differential equation is $d(e^{xy}) + 2ydy = 0 \\ as \space d(e^{xy})=ye^{xy}dx+xe^{xy}dy \\ \implies e^{xy} + y^2 = c, \space some \space constant$

Comment: Sir, can you answer this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2875818/394202