# Solve: $(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2axy)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve: $(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2axy)dy=0$

The given differential equation is not exact.

The given differential equation is homogeneous.

Therefore,

$I.F=\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$

$=\frac{1}{(3xy-2ay^2)x+(x^2-2axy)y}$

$=\frac{1}{xy(4x-4ay)}$

With Integrating Factor of this form (ugly value), it is difficult to compute further integration, that is involved in solving the equation.

**So, can we not solve the equation using the rule:**

> If in the differential eqn $Mdx+Ndy=0$, provided $ Mx+Ny \ne 0$, andM
>   and N ar eboth homogeneous then
>
> $I.F=\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$

Comment: put $y=vx,$ .............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$(3xy-2ay^2)dx+(x^2-2axy)dy=0$$
With
$$M=3xy-2ay^2~~~~~~,~~~~~~N=x^2-2axy$$
then
$$M_y=3x-4ay~~~~~~,~~~~~~N_x=2x-2ay$$
so the equation is not exact. For integrating factor 
$$\mu=\dfrac{M_y-N_x}{N}=\dfrac{x-2ay}{x(x-2ay)}=\dfrac1x$$
therefore $I=e^{\int \mu\ dx}=x$ is integrating factor.

---

**Can you proceed?**

Comment: Yes, I can proceed like this. But, can we not solve it using the homogeneous method?

Comment: other answer is wity homogeneous method

Comment: I see that it can be solved by any of the three methods.
1. $Mx+Ny$
2. $Mx-Ny$
3. And the one you showed

Answer (score 1):

Put y=vx

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2ay^2-3xy}{x^2-2axy}  \\ v+x\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2av^2-3v}{1-2av}\\x\frac{dv}{dx} =\frac{4v(av-1)}{1-2av} \\ \frac{1-2av}{4v(av-1)}dv=\frac{dx}{x} \\(\frac{-1}{4v}-\frac{a}{4(av-1)})dv=\frac{dx}{x}\\v(av-1)x^4=C\\x^2y(ay-x)=C, \space some \space constant$

> Other simpler way would be multiply with x

Given differential equation becomes:

$d(x^3 y)-ad(x^2y^2)=0$

U can directly integrate from here

Comment: Sir, can you please help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2881062/394202